# ''Having you is happy for me'' VS ''Having you makes me happy''

Tags: word-choice, grammar, adjectives, word-order

We can use happy like in "happy endings", "happy story", "happy summer" etc. in order to mean that those things make us or made us happy.

But the following sounds weird to me.

> Having you is happy for me

For example, the sentence “This story is very happy for me” doesn't sound weird to me but the other one does. Is that sentence wrong or not? I need your help.

Edit:
Another example: We can say

> It was sad for me to lose.

but why can't we say the following?

> It was happy for me to win.

If we can't say the sentence above, why does: “The day was happy for me.” sound OK?

Comment: 'John is happy for me' is idiomatic, but means 'John is happy to see me doing well [in the situation mentioned]'.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but this doesn't answer my question. :)

Comment: I think your *sad/happy* comparison makes for a stronger question. You might want to consider editing your question's title and body along those lines - perhaps something like **"Why '(It) was sad to see you go' but '(I) was happy to see you return'?"**. I'm using brackets here just to highlight the difference between the two. Note that replacing *happy* with *delightful* sounds fine.

Comment: Though 'Having you as my enemy makes me sad' and 'It is sad for me to have you as my enemy' are both idiomatic, 'Having you as my friend makes me happy' is idiomatic whereas 'It is happy for me to have you as my friend' sounds off to my ear. [This post at Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/grammar/comments/37ajyf/a_little_trouble_with_it_is_adj_infinitive_clause/) argues its acceptability, with conflicting views; I'd say that the acceptability of 'It is Adj for me to' and 'Having you ... is Adj for me' depends on the specific adjective.

Comment: A happy ending or happy story is not described that way because it made you happy - in English if something is described as "happy" it is understood as an (objective) intrinsic quality of that thing. If you say "this story is very happy for me" you are saying that, in your opinion, the story is happy, not that it brought you any particular feelings of happiness. To express that meaning, you do have to say "the story makes me happy." But that doesn't answer WHY it's that way, which I will keep thinking about.

Comment: @Edwin So if I want to say that something makes me happy, I can't use happy as an adjective except in the instances like ''The day was happy.'', ''The movie was  happy.", "Our marriage was happy for me."etc.? But why? For example say that I am a basketball player, after a game I can say ''It was a sad game for us.'' or "The game made us happy" but not "It was a happy game for us"? I can say ''It was a happy day for us" but not "It was a happy game for us"? I can't understand.

Comment: @Lawrence So, if I want to say how something made me feel for example I can't say ''The final match was happy for me" but I can say "The final match was delightful for me" or "The final match was sad for me"? Also you are a native English speaker, right?

Comment: Placement of English adjectives is not totally predictable. Sometimes, even the length of the adjective seems to influence where it is normally used. _Inconsolable, she dashed out of the room_ sounds far better than _Sad, she dashed out of the room_. //  'It was a happy day' sounds far better than 'The day was happy' (note that this is a transferred usage; days don't feel emotions). Sorry; English is far from easy. Idiomaticity doesn't obey invariant rules, and takes a lifetime to get to grips with. By which time it's changed.

Comment: @MAA Exactly. As Edwin notes, idiomacity is idiosyncratic. One does not say "the story was happy" for the reason you give, yet the phrase "a happy story" seems to fit all the same objections and yet is idiomatic.

Comment: @DereMemo Yes, you can use *delightful* and *sad* that way, even without the trailing "for me".

Comment: @Lawrence Thanks. Btw MAA said ''A happy ending or happy story is not described that way because it made you happy..." but one of the descriptions about the word happy on Oxford dictionary is this:        ''Giving or causing pleasure. Examples:
a happy marriage/memory/childhood
The story has a happy ending.
Those were the happiest days of my life.''

Comment: And also in the dictionary of Cambridge the definition of happy is  ''feeling, showing, or 'causing' pleasure or satisfaction''

Comment: [It was a GOOD match / game for us](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/399149/can-i-say-having-you-is-happy-for-me-instead-of-having-you-makes-me-happy#comment946783_399149) strongly implies that you were pleased (happy) with its results or scores. A FUN movie, is an enjoyable movie. A HAPPY movie, means the plot is lighthearted and carefree. But a movie MAKES you feel sad / happy / good / frightened / etc.

Comment: "Having you makes me happy," said the lion to the zebra.